# Proving a binomial identity involving the sum of a product of four binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

While working on a problem, I needed to prove the following identity:

> For all $i,j,m,n \geqslant 0$,
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k+\ell=m} k! \ell! \binom{n+k-1}{k} \binom{j-i}{k} \binom{n-j+m-1}{\ell} \binom{i}{\ell} = m! \binom{n-i+m-1}{m}\binom{j}{m}.
> \end{align*}

Computational evidence indicates that this is true, but I haven't been able to prove it. It looks a little like Vandermonde's identity, but I haven't been able to massage it into a form where I can just apply that. Is there a clever way to prove this identity?

Comment: This has hints of Vandermonde (choosing $m$ things can be done by all ways to choose $k$ then $l$ things), and also some stars-and-bars looking terms.  Could you tell us where this comes from?  Perhaps given the problem setting one might be more inspired to find a combinatorial proof (as opposed to proof by tedious algebraic manipulation).

Comment: I'm working with the so-called Jordan plane, the quotient of the free algebra $k\langle x,y \rangle$ by the relation $yx = xy+y^2$. I wanted to write down the commutator of two monomials (depending on $n$, $i$ and $j$) and the need to prove this identity popped out.

Comment: Haha, I have no idea what you just said, so I guess that didn't help (at least, not me).  Thanks anyway...  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
\begin{align}
F(m,k)
&=k! (m-k)! \binom{n+k-1}{k} \binom{j-i}{k} \binom{n-j+m-1}{m-k} \binom{i}{m-k}
\\\\
&=\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}\binom{j-i}{k}\frac{(n-j+m-1)!}{(n-j+k-1)!}\binom{i}{m-k}
\end{align}
denote the summand. Let 
$$
S_m=\sum_{k=0}^m F(m,k)
$$ be the sum to be computed.

Define $G(m,k)$ as follows. The motivation for this definition is as of yet unclear$^{**}$:
\begin{align}
G(m,k)
&=F(m,k)\cdot \frac{k\,\left(m-k-i\right)\,\left(n+k-j-1\right)}
{m-k+1}
\\\\
&=\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-1)!}\binom{j-i}{k}\frac{(n-j+m-1)!}{(n-j+k-1)!}\color{red}{\binom{i+1}{m-k+1}}\frac{k\,\left(m-k-i\right)\,\left(n+k-j-1\right)}
{\color{red}{i+1}}
\end{align}
Note that the first expression for $G(m,k)$ is undefined when $k=m+1$, as it contains $\frac00$. However, it can be rearranged to the second expression, where $G(m,k)$ is unambiguously defined for all $k$. Note that $G(m,k)=0$ for all $k$ outside $[1,m+1]$.

You can verify via tedious algebraic manipulations$^*$ that
$$
(m+1)F(m+1,k)-(j-m)(n+m-i)F(m,k)=G(m,k+1)-G(m,k)\label1\tag1
$$
holds for all nonnegative integer inputs.

Now, sum both sides of the above equation from $k=0$ to $m+1$. The right had side is a telescoping sum. We attain
$$
(m+1)S_{m+1}-(j-m)(n+m-i)S_m=G(m,m+2)-G(m,0)=0-0,
$$
or
$$
S_{m+1}=\frac{(j-m)(n+m-i)}{m+1}S_m
$$
This easily lets you prove that $S_m=m!\binom{n-i+m-1}{m}\binom{j}m$ by induction.

---

$^*$ The calculations really are tedious, but certainly feasible for even a high schooler to do. Start by dividing $\eqref1$ though by $F(m,k)$, then replace all of the binomial coefficients with factorials. Every factorial term in the numerator will have a counterpart which cancels nicely with one in the denominator. For example, in $F(m+1,k)/F(m,k)$, there will appear $$\binom{i}{m+1-k}\Big/\binom{i}{m-k}=\frac{i!}{(m+1-k)!(i-m-1+k)!}\Big/\frac{i!}{(m-k)!(i-m+k)!}=\frac{i-m+k}{m+1-k}$$
After making all these cancellations, you will be left with a sum of fractions of polynomials in $i,j,k,m,n$. After clearing denominators, this is a polynomial equation which can be verified by collecting all like coefficients.

But there is not reason not to just have Mathematica verify the equation for you automatically.

```
F[m_,k_] := k! * (m-k)! * 
            Binomial[n+k-1,k] * Binomial[j-i,k] * 
            Binomial[n-j+m-1,m-k] * Binomial[i,m-k];

G[m_,k_] := F[m,k] * k * (m - k - i) * (n + k - j - 1) / (m - k + 1);

Print[
  FullSimplify[
    FunctionExpand[
    (m + 1)F[m + 1,k] - (j - m)(n + m - i)F[m,k] == G[m,k + 1] - G[m,k]
    ]
  ]
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU7NCsIwDD7bp4i3za2IV2UXwe0qeCxlFH8w61JFNtCnn0mnogcLbfMl@X7IdecjuQ73bhhKQ3XuawvLAvwUZpCQ9qkUCr7OGsOF0LUmZF4vcm954dNrNI6dPxTdZMQkFv6hYeyslKq@MnCeUcvHLKC50ICpoABZRA3fRQrz9zxjxDLbG4bOcIayb9sd0rXF08PETGUf9h1ewuZ@deFg1ISZwmI3@cVRQyK6lEYbiqavMEUBlVSyKosR2Cgsr1V2GJ4)

---

$^{**}$ The quotient $ \frac{k\,\left(m-k-i\right)\,\left(n+k-j-1\right)}{m-k+1}$ in the definition of $G$, and the coefficients $m+1$ and $i(j-m)(n+m-i)$ on the left hand side of $\eqref1$, are attained using Zeilberger's algorithm. Specifically, I used the programming language Maxima, this code snippet:

```
load (zeilberger)$

Zeilberger  
(
    k! * (m-k)! * 
    binomial(n+k-1,k) * binomial(j-i,k) * binomial(n-j+m-1,m-k) * binomial(i,m-k)
    ,k,m
);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc5BCgIxDAXQdXOKCC5Sp1241Zu462CVTJoWygiDl6@ti0Hchcfn/2jYWENrqYQ70jtymmN9xmqPAOW1XvC2kwECIwc8IakXOw4wM@eiHBLlSfzZie262@L5T7JfJu25UfDr/BUwDsWhwlh/lLrWkKl/Ya@tfQA) (ignore the small differences in the linked code).

This algorithm, and others is discussed in the book *A = B* by Marko Petkovsek, Herbert Wilf and Doron Zeilberger, [available for free online](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html). Basically, the book shows must summations similar to yours can be solved completely automatically, and computer verifiable proofs of these equation can also be produced automatically.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. I have a couple of small corrections (although I might be missing something). We need to define $G(m,m+1) = -(m+1) F(m+1,m+1)$, rather than $0$. This means that when we sum (1) for $k$ between $0$ and $m$ (rather than $-1$ and $m$) we obtain $(m+1) \sum_{k=0}^m F(m+1,k) - (j-m)(n+m-i) S_m = - G(m,m+1)$, which then rearranges as claimed.

Comment: @lokodiz I have (hopefully) fixed the mistake. I did so in a way more in line with the general theory. Note that it is okay to sum both sides from $0$ to $m+1$, because $F(m,m+1)=0$ anyway.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k+\ell=m} k! \ell! \binom{n+k-1}{k} \binom{j-i}{k} \binom{n-j+m-1}{\ell} \binom{i}{\ell} = m! \binom{n-i+m-1}{m}\binom{j}{m}.
\end{align*}
Okay, first thing I'd do, is expand the sum termwise a bit to cancel things to be:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k+\ell=m} \frac{(n+k-1)!i!}{(n-1)!(i-\ell)!} \binom{j-i}{k} \binom{n-j+m-1}{\ell} = m! \binom{n-i+m-1}{m}\binom{j}{m}.
\end{align*}
Scanning a bit more, we see the possibility to get rid of $m!$ on the right hand side:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k+\ell=m} \frac{(n+k-1)!i!}{(n-1)!(i-\ell)!} \binom{j-i}{k} \binom{n-j+m-1}{\ell} = \frac{(n-i+m-1)!}{(n-i-1)!}\binom{j}{m}.
\end{align*}
Using the fact (finally...) that $k+\ell=m$, noting that means $m!$ has $\ell!$ and $k!$ as factors, remaining factor p,we get:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k+\ell=m} \frac{p(n+k-1)!(i)!(j-i)!(n-j+m-1)!}{(n-1)!(i-\ell)!(j-i-k)!(n-j+k-1)!} = \frac{p(n-i+m-1)!(j)!}{(n-i-1)!(j-m)!}.
\end{align*}

Looking a bit closer, we have $$\ell\leq i\leq j\leq n, m\leq n,k\leq j, k\leq n$$ As well as simplifying because factorials in denominators have a factor separating them, we can go down to:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k+\ell=m} qsrt(n+k-1)!= uvp^2
\end{align*}
Where p,q,r,s,t,u, and v are all quotients of factorials. So, you have the statement that, a factorial and a square of a quotient of factorials, can be related by another set of 6 not necessarily distinct quotients of factorials,

Comment: Yes I'll work it again to double check later.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't particularly useful as it stands. I'd already been able to make the same "simplifications" you did, but the form of the claimed identity I gave seemed the cleanest. In any case, I don't have a proof that my claimed identity is true, and all of your manipulations hinge on its validity.

Comment: all my manipulations, hinge on the claimed nonnegative integer values, and factorial properties, actually. in a proof you can assume validity to prove consistency with the axioms used, if not you get a proof by contradiction.